# How do I prevent the Office add-in from being disabled due to delayed loading?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I have an Office add-on being disabled due to delayed loading. In the ThisAddIn_Startup event, I need to perform an operation that might be performed for a few seconds. I already changed the code to run asynchronously, but even so Outlook eventually marks the component as causing slowdowns and disables its functioning, causing the end user to open calls to the support area.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => BackgroundService.Load(this.Application));
}
```

Comment: What I do is make slow initialization happen after start up.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that OOM cannot be accessed on a secondarily thread, so I am surprised it works for you at all.

Another option is starting a `Timer` in `ThisAddIn_Startup` (use `Timer` from the Forms namespace since it fires on the main thread) - when it fires, Outlook won't be looking and the time won't count against your addin.

Comment: i will try this approach. Sounds good. If it resolves the issue, I will come back to mark as right answer. Thank you.